# Embed Google Map code in HTML with marker

Tags: html, google-maps

I have several places with their latitude and longitude. I want to display them in google map. Thats ok, what i can't is to display the marker at the specific lat,long position.

e.g. if i've the following code, is it possible just to place an option to display the market as well because all the lat,long coord are comming from a database and echoed with php

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
        marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
        src="http://maps.google.mu/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-20.234496,57.603722&amp;spn=0.093419,0.169086&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;
        output=embed"></iframe>
        <br />
        <small><a href="http://maps.google.mu/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-20.234496,57.603722
                  &amp;spn=0.093419,0.169086&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;source=embed"
               style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map
               </a>
        </small>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The  element that you posted looks like it's just copy-pasted from the Google Maps embed feature.

If you'd like to drop markers for the locations that you have, you'll need to write some JavaScript to do so.  I'm learning how to do this as well.

Check out the following:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

It has several examples and code samples that can be easily re-used and adapted to fit your current problem.

Answer (score 46):

I would suggest this way, one line iframe.
no javascript needed at all.
In query ?q=,

```html
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=12.927923,77.627108&z=15&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: &output=embed is no longer supported.

Answer (score 9):

no javascript or third party 'tools' necessary, use this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<YOUR API KEY>&q=71.0378379,-110.05995059999998"></iframe>
```

the place parameter provides the marker

there are a few options for the format of the 'q' parameter

make sure you have Google Maps Embed API and Static Maps API enabled in your APIs, or google will block the request

for more information check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

Comment: Exactly what is needed if you want to use only embedding (currently free) & display a marker using long&lat from database - perfect!

Answer (score 6):

Learning Google's JavaScript library is a good option. If you don't feel like getting into coding you might find [Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) useful.

It is a tool recently published by Google where you can create your personal maps (create markers, draw geometries and adapt the colors and styles).

Here is an useful tutorial I found:
[Quick Tip: Embedding New Google Maps](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/applications/quick-tip-embedding-new-google-maps/)

Answer (score 1):

USE this , Don't forget to get a google api key from

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

and replace it

```
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(38.224905, 48.252143);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 16};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
  marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```