# Google Maps: Add a marker to the embedded Google map without their API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From google map I can get the embeded link like this:

```
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d14758.879464292155!2d114.13797844999998!3d22.364204!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2shk!4v1439431516910" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it works perfectly.The problem is I would like to add a marker on the map

e.g. a market pointing 22.364204,114.1379784 , 15z

I have tried search a while and some discussion suggested that I can use parameter `&q=`

so I add the parameter

```
&q=22.364204,114.1379784&z=15&output=embed
```

and the final code

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d14758.879464292155!2d114.13797844999998!3d22.364204!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2shk!4v1439431516910&q=22.364204,114.1379784&z=15&output=embed" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but the marker doesn not appear. Any ideas about that? Any approach is without using their js api?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you point us to the "discussion" you are talking about? That discussion may be solving a different issue than yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415842/embed-google-map-code-in-html-with-marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the link you provided it works as expected by removing the extra parameter "pb".

```html
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=22.364204,114.1379784&z=15&output=embed" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: it works! great. One last question, can I customized the search message at the top left corner instead of the point 22.364204,114.1379784, is that means I need to put &q=USA ROAD instead of the exact lat lng?

Comment: Not sure but you can accept this answer and post a different one so that they can stay on topic in SO :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).  There is a [wizard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) to help you create the map.

**parameters**

```
q=22.364204,114.1379784 (marker location)
zoom=15                 (initial zoom level)
```

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=22.364204%2C114.1379784&key=AIzaSyCF5T43TaYZfv7RLFwFPXrPNFpDiC6ffO4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_20150812.html)

Comment: Thanks for the information. And I afraid without API is more prefer

Answer (score 1):

i use this code
on html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

on javascript

```
 var map;
enter code here
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.000009, -56.197645),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var mapCanvas = document.createElement("div");
mapCanvas.id = "canvas";
mapCanvas.style.width = "800px";
mapCanvas.style.height = "400px";
 document.body.appendChild(mapCanvas);
map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.000009, -56.197645),
    map: map,
    title: 'marker'
 //=====You can even customize the icons here
});
}
```

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);